# Windows 10 client gives incorrect password when disconnected from domain network

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, windows-domain

I have several Windows 10 clients but have an issue with just one, it's on build 14955 but had the same issue on the previous pre-release also.  Machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain client.

When on the LAN the main user account (domain admin) can login to the machine fine but when disconnected from the LAN it presents incorrect password even though the password is known good.  Domain name is home.local which definitely isn't resolving when disconnected.

This has me baffled.

Comment: Why is the domain name incorrect? Have you added home.local to the hosts file of the problem client?  have you tried to add and remove the client from the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have been having exactly the same issue.  Windows Hello won't login because it says that the password has been changed from a different device.  It hasn't.  When reconnected to the domain network everything works (login from password or windows hello).  I was wondering if this is related to the PIN.  I did set one a while ago but couldn't remember it, and have been trying various PIN combination in an effort to guess it.  I hadn't reset the PIN as the message suggests possible data loss from doing so: [Are you sure?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPB5v.png) Anyways, after joining back to the corporate wifi, resetting the PIN, and the disconnecting from the WIFI again, I can now login when not connected to the domain.

Comment: Note that I am on build 14955 also.

Comment: AFAIK I don't have a PIN setup however when I have the machine back on the domain LAN I will double-check.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi Rik, I've just checked and there is no PIN setup for the user in question

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with that particular windows insider build which was resolved in the subsequent update.